# Почему на Ipad не появляется кнопка "sign in with apple"?

Tags: vue.js, ios, cordova

У меня есть мобильное приложение
Его стек

```
Apache Cordova 12
Vue.js
Laravel
```

[image: Мой стенд]

На моих стендах (Личный телефон и виртуализация хоста от xcode все работает)

В ответе от техподдержки я вижу скрин на котором данной функции входа - нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начал проводить расследование и дошел до того, что кнопка не появляется на Ipad

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код для авторизации

```
import MessengerButton from "@/components/Utils/MessengerButton.vue";
import Button from "@/components/Utils/Button.vue";
import Input from "@/components/Utils/Input.vue";
import PrivacyPolicy from "@/components/Login/PrivacyPolicy.vue";
import { mapActions, mapMutations, mapState } from "vuex";
import LoginFooter from "@/components/Login/LoginFooter.vue";
import MobileDetect from "mobile-detect";
import { sendAppleAuthInfo } from "@/api";
import("mobile-detect")

export default {
  name: "AuthRegForm",
  components: {
    LoginFooter,
    PrivacyPolicy,
    Input,
    Button,
    MessengerButton
  },
  props: {
    type: String,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('auth', ['authError']),

    getRoute() {
      return this.$route.path
    },
    // getSessionId() {
    //   return this.$route.fullPath.split('?session_id=')[1]
    // },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      telephone: '',
      name: { value: '' },
      mdClass: '',
      error : '',
      session: { id: '' },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('auth', ['authWithToken']),
    ...mapMutations('auth', ['SET_DATA_AUTH', 'SET_DATA_REGISTRATION']),

    setTelephone(tel) {
      this.telephone = tel
      this.error = ''
    },
    setName(name) {
      this.name.value = name
      this.error = ''
    },
    sendCode() {
      let phone = +this.telephone.replace(/\D/g, "")
      console.log('phone', phone)

      if (String(phone).length === 11 && this.name.value || this.$route.path === '/auth') {
        let device_name = this.mdClass.mobile() + this.mdClass.userAgent();
        console.log("DeviceName = " + device_name)

        if (typeof device_name !== "string") {
          device_name = "browser"
        }

        const data = {
          phone,
          name: this.name.value,
          device_name
        }

        const appleSessionId = this.$route.fullPath.split('?apple_session_id=')[1]
        console.log('appleSessionId', appleSessionId)

        if (this.$route.path === '/auth' && !appleSessionId) {
          console.log('this', this.session)
          this.$store.dispatch('auth/authSendCode', data)
        } else if (this.$route.path === '/reg' || appleSessionId) {
          this.$store.dispatch('auth/registrationSendCode', this.session.id ? {
            ...data,
            session_id: this.session.id
          } : data)
        }
      } else {
        this.error = 'Не все поля заполнены'
      }
    },
    setTokens(url) {
      const authWithToken = (data) => this.authWithToken(data)
      const thisSession = this.session

      const token = url.split('?token=')?.[1]?.replace('%7C', '|')
      const sessionId = url.split('?session_id=')[1]
      const appleSessionId = url.split('?apple_session_id=')[1]

      if (token) {
        authWithToken({ token, goToProfile: true })
      }

      if (sessionId && this.$route === '/auth') {
        this.$router.push(`/reg?session_id=${sessionId}`)
      }

      if (appleSessionId && this.$route === '/reg') {
        this.$router.push(`/auth?apple_session_id=${appleSessionId}`)
      }

      if (sessionId || appleSessionId) {
        thisSession.id = sessionId ?? appleSessionId
      }
    },
    auth() {
      const setTokens = (url) => this.setTokens(url)

      setTokens(this.$route.fullPath)
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

        window.handleOpenURL = function(url) {
          // Обработка URL
          setTokens(url)
          // Разбор параметров и выполнение нужных действий
        };
      }, false);

      const MobileDetect = require('mobile-detect')

      this.mdClass = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent)
    },
    appleAuth() {
      const authWithToken = (data) => this.authWithToken(data)
      const thisSession = this.session
      const thisName = this.name
      const route = this.$route.fullPath
      const router = this.$router

      try {
        cordova.plugins.SignInWithApple.signin(
            {requestedScopes: [0, 1]},
            function (success) {
              sendAppleAuthInfo(success).then(r => {
                const user = r.data.data

                if (user.session) {
                  if (route === '/reg') {
                    router.push(`/auth?apple_session_id=${user.session}`)
                  }

                  thisSession.id = user.session
                  thisName.value = user.name

                } else {
                  authWithToken({ token: user.token, goToProfile: true })
                }
              })
            },
            function (error) {
              console.error(error);
              alert('error - ' + JSON.stringify(error))
            }
        )
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e.toString())
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    'this.$route.fullPath'() {
      this.auth()
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.auth()
    this.SET_DATA_AUTH({})
    this.SET_DATA_REGISTRATION({})
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="auth-reg-form">
    <div class="auth-reg-form__inputs">
      <Input
          placeholder="Имя"
          @input-value="setName"
          v-if="getRoute === '/reg'"
      />
      <Input
          type="tel"
          placeholder="Телефон"
          :error="error || authError?.message"
          :show-error="error || authError?.message"
          @input-value="setTelephone"
          input-mask="+7 (###) ###-##-##"
      />
      <Input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Пароль"
          v-if="type === 'password'"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="auth-reg-form__buttons" :class="type === 'sms' ? 'auth-reg-form__buttons_mt-24' : 'auth-reg-form__buttons_mt-16'">
      <Button
          type="submit"
          name="Применить"
          @click-btn="sendCode"
      />
      <Button class="bg-transparent" name="Назад" @click="$router.push('/')"/>
    </div>

    <slot name="textWithLink"/>

    <PrivacyPolicy/>
    <LoginFooter @apple-auth="appleAuth"/>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
@import '@/assets/scss/views/login/authRegForm';
</style>
```